# How see today 'date in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

i have a sheet that contains 2000 rows of date and i want when open my sheet, open sheet in today date
how can i do this ?
I sent my picture of my sheet
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zoGX.png)

i've search in internet but not found any results

Comment: You can enter at the top of the sheet a formula that creates a link to the cell which corresponds to today's date. If you need help implementing this, please share a sample sheet or [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function gotodate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const dA = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,1).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const dt = new Date();
  const d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"M/d/yyyy");
  let idx = dA.indexOf(d)
  if(~idx) {
    sh.getRange(idx + 2,1).activate();
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Sheet0:

| Date | HDR2 | HDR3 | HDR4 | HDR5 | HDR6 | HDR7 | HDR8 | HDR9 | HDR10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6/29/2023 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 0 | 6 |
| 6/30/2023 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 7 | 8 |
| 7/1/2023 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 7 | 3 |
| 7/2/2023 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 6 | 2 | 7 | 10 | 9 |
| 7/3/2023 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 10 | 10 | 6 |
| 7/4/2023 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 7 | 2 | 6 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 7/5/2023 | 3 | 7 | 5 | 5 | 10 | 2 | 0 | 5 | 4 |
| 7/6/2023 | 3 | 6 | 8 | 7 | 1 | 0 | 12 | 10 | 0 |
| 7/7/2023 | 0 | 2 | 8 | 1 | 6 | 8 | 7 | 13 | 4 |
| 7/8/2023 | 0 | 5 | 11 | 12 | 9 | 7 | 13 | 1 | 16 |
| 7/9/2023 | 6 | 8 | 11 | 1 | 6 | 2 | 8 | 6 | 12 |
| 7/10/2023 | 11 | 4 | 3 | 11 | 1 | 13 | 8 | 4 | 16 |
| 7/11/2023 | 2 | 0 | 6 | 10 | 11 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 6 |
| 7/12/2023 | 6 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 0 | 11 |
| 7/13/2023 | 4 | 6 | 15 | 6 | 13 | 10 | 5 | 2 | 14 |
| 7/14/2023 | 8 | 12 | 1 | 14 | 1 | 2 | 16 | 17 | 6 |
| 7/15/2023 | 8 | 7 | 9 | 6 | 19 | 13 | 8 | 9 | 17 |
| 7/16/2023 | 7 | 18 | 12 | 13 | 18 | 14 | 15 | 0 | 21 |
| 7/17/2023 | 5 | 16 | 8 | 3 | 22 | 0 | 17 | 22 | 0 |
| 7/18/2023 | 6 | 18 | 10 | 3 | 8 | 7 | 1 | 24 | 11 |
| 7/19/2023 | 4 | 14 | 18 | 18 | 15 | 25 | 6 | 24 | 0 |
| 7/20/2023 | 8 | 11 | 4 | 14 | 15 | 1 | 26 | 1 | 29 |
| 7/21/2023 | 9 | 21 | 20 | 1 | 24 | 16 | 21 | 26 | 17 |
| 7/22/2023 | 21 | 15 | 16 | 10 | 24 | 16 | 5 | 28 | 9 |
| 7/23/2023 | 1 | 2 | 10 | 15 | 9 | 7 | 21 | 19 | 32 |
| 7/24/2023 | 18 | 1 | 0 | 6 | 18 | 16 | 28 | 26 | 19 |
| 7/25/2023 | 10 | 0 | 25 | 22 | 30 | 0 | 3 | 31 | 6 |
| 7/26/2023 | 19 | 0 | 24 | 1 | 31 | 22 | 33 | 4 | 8 |
| 7/27/2023 | 2 | 20 | 5 | 6 | 5 | 5 | 20 | 32 | 1 |
| 7/28/2023 | 14 | 25 | 10 | 32 | 15 | 20 | 33 | 22 | 8 |
| 7/29/2023 | 0 | 28 | 7 | 24 | 19 | 19 | 10 | 34 | 28 |
| 7/30/2023 | 5 | 9 | 31 | 32 | 5 | 12 | 19 | 9 | 23 |
| 7/31/2023 | 23 | 32 | 20 | 13 | 32 | 30 | 31 | 29 | 16 |
| 8/1/2023 | 2 | 31 | 27 | 5 | 8 | 34 | 2 | 22 | 24 |
| 8/2/2023 | 19 | 28 | 16 | 28 | 36 | 38 | 27 | 9 | 25 |
| 8/3/2023 | 31 | 30 | 21 | 32 | 38 | 20 | 5 | 38 | 0 |
| 8/4/2023 | 19 | 26 | 23 | 15 | 24 | 20 | 9 | 4 | 20 |
| 8/5/2023 | 1 | 30 | 13 | 39 | 33 | 24 | 7 | 25 | 39 |
| 8/6/2023 | 15 | 3 | 31 | 5 | 21 | 41 | 35 | 43 | 25 |
| 8/7/2023 | 34 | 32 | 10 | 24 | 15 | 30 | 3 | 42 | 40 |
| 8/8/2023 | 8 | 26 | 39 | 16 | 11 | 20 | 19 | 28 | 35 |
| 8/9/2023 | 37 | 14 | 16 | 17 | 8 | 28 | 43 | 14 | 15 |
| 8/10/2023 | 30 | 21 | 8 | 26 | 2 | 19 | 37 | 37 | 37 |
| 8/11/2023 | 23 | 4 | 22 | 18 | 42 | 26 | 35 | 37 | 3 |
| 8/12/2023 | 26 | 43 | 25 | 40 | 38 | 42 | 7 | 32 | 37 |
| 8/13/2023 | 18 | 6 | 8 | 27 | 37 | 31 | 8 | 25 | 8 |
| 8/14/2023 | 43 | 27 | 40 | 32 | 48 | 14 | 23 | 48 | 3 |
| 8/15/2023 | 2 | 42 | 38 | 49 | 24 | 15 | 36 | 8 | 21 |
| 8/16/2023 | 12 | 15 | 47 | 42 | 45 | 13 | 26 | 10 | 3 |
| 8/17/2023 | 34 | 22 | 22 | 18 | 46 | 4 | 7 | 26 | 43 |
| 8/18/2023 | 22 | 13 | 12 | 49 | 39 | 55 | 11 | 24 | 3 |
| 8/19/2023 | 35 | 47 | 32 | 23 | 18 | 26 | 15 | 40 | 53 |

Answer (score 0):

The easy way will be to use CTRL + F and then search for today's date. I think their is no other efficient method. Because function like VLOOKUP just tell you if their is a value or not, it's not selecting the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, do you want to highlight today's date from your list of dates every time you access your sheet? You can try to do **[Conditional Formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413)** with the following parameters:

1. On "Apply to Range" you can declare the entire column of dates
2. On "Format Rules" you can set it to "is equal to" then under the "Value or formula" text box, enter the formula `=today()` indicating that any cell that matches today's date will be highlighted

To add to this, you can also add a separate conditional formatting rule for the days of the week to be highlighted as well. The same rules above will apply, but on the "Value or formula" text box, the formula will now be `=text(today(), "DDD")` to highlight the shortened version of today's day (similar to what you have on your screenshot)

However, this rule would match all days within the column, as shown in the [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/42333FO):

**Here are some links as well for the formulas used, for your reference:**

- [TODAY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984?hl=en)
- [TEXT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en)

Let me know if I was able to properly understand and answer your question. If not, I would really appreciate further clarifications or details on your problem.